# foreach loop in php needs debugging

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

While I had no success with php routing since is above my current knowledge I tried the implementation below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE SURNAME LIKE 'Ω%' ORDER BY SURNAME ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); //the selected query has 2 results!

/* determine number of rows result set */
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

printf("results (%d).", $row_cnt);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

function generateTableFromResult($result) {
    $x = 1;
    $html = "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            copy("persons.php","newfile".$x.".php");
            $html.="<tr><th>".$column."</th><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
            $myfile = fopen("newfile".$x.".php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($myfile, $html);
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $html .= "</table>";
    return $html;
}

// usage:
// ...
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo generateTableFromResult($result);`
```

The above script creates:

```
newfile1.php --> table + table (first + second result)
newfile2.php --> table + table (first + second result)
```

while I want:

```
newfile1.php --> table (first result)
newfile2.php --> table (second result)
```

What am I missing here?

edit:

example content of `newfile1.php`:

`CODE_NO    12101
SURNAME ΩΝΑΣΗ
FIRST_NAME  ΧΡΙΣΤΙΝΑ
SOURCE1 ΗΛΙΟΥ
SOURCE2 
SOURCE3 
PROV    ΟΙΚΟΓΕΝΕΙΑΚΗ ΣΧΕΣΗ ΚΑΘΕΤΗ ΜΕ ΚΙΝΗΤΙΚΟΤΗΤΑ
SEX ΓΥΝΑΙΚΑ
BIRTH   1950
DEATH   1989
PLACE   ΜΕΓΑΛΟ ΑΣΤΙΚΟ ΚΕΝΤΡΟ
REGION  ΑΛΛΕΣ ΞΕΝΕΣ ΧΩΡΕΣ
EDUCATION   ΜΕΤΑΠΤΥΧΙΑΚΕΣ ΣΠΟΥΔΕΣ
SPECIAL 
WRITING 
POLITICAL

MANAGERIAL

MILITARY

RELIGIOUS

SPIRITUAL

SCIENTIFIC

NOBLE   ΝΑΙ
CULTURAL

FINANCIAL   ΝΑΙ
CONSTITUTIONAL

OPPOSITION

PROF1   Επιχειρηματίας
PROF2   Νεώτερη αριστοκρατική ελίτ πλουτου
PROF3

PROF4

PROF5

PARTY

ACTIVITY1

ACTIVITY2

1800_1832

1833_1862

1863_1911

1912_1922

1923_1944

1945_1973   ΝΑΙ
1974_   ΝΑΙ
HIERARCHY   Ανωτάτη Ελίτ
LEADERSHIP`

**HERE starts table 2** This is what tables look like. Remember I want each table to be written per person/file.

`CODE_NO    12100
SURNAME ΩΝΑΣΗΣ
FIRST_NAME  ΑΡΙΣΤΟΤΕΛΗΣ
SOURCE1 ΗΛΙΟΥ
SOURCE2 ΔΡΑΝΔΑΚΗ
SOURCE3 ΕΚΔΟΤΙΚΗ
PROV    ΑΓΝΩΣΤΗ
SEX ΑΝΔΡΑΣ
BIRTH   1906
DEATH   1975
PLACE   ΑΓΡΟΤΙΚΕΣ- ΝΗΣΙΩΤΙΚΕΣ
REGION  ΜΙΚΡΑ ΑΣΙΑ
EDUCATION   ΔΕΝ ΔΗΛΩΝΕΙ
SPECIAL 
WRITING 
POLITICAL

MANAGERIAL

MILITARY

RELIGIOUS

SPIRITUAL

SCIENTIFIC

NOBLE   ΝΑΙ
CULTURAL

FINANCIAL   ΝΑΙ
CONSTITUTIONAL

OPPOSITION

PROF1   Εφοπλιστής
PROF2   Νεώτερη αριστοκρατική ελίτ πλουτου
PROF3

PROF4

PROF5

PARTY

ACTIVITY1

ACTIVITY2

1800_1832

1833_1862

1863_1911

1912_1922

1923_1944   ΝΑΙ
1945_1973   ΝΑΙ
1974_

HIERARCHY   Yψιστη Μορφή Ελίτ
LEADERSHIP`

Comment: I think you need to move `$x++` up inside the foreach loop. Otherwise `copy` will overwrite the new file, and something else is wrong with your code. You probably also want to move `$html = "<table>";` down inside at least one loop; otherwise you'll keep appending. I'm not sure exactly where to move it.

Comment: @jh1711 - I rather thing the file copy should be before the `foreach` and the write after. If the OP just moves `$x++` inside the `foreach`, the OP will end up with one file per column instead of one file per person. There's simply a lot of logical mistakes here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, you are probably right about the files. I'm not sure about `$html` anymore, because it's used to write to two files and returned. I hope kapelnick can clarify.

Comment: on a side note, you would usually not create a whole bunch of files like that, but just call the db and show the results as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should produce the output you want (from your comments):

```
function generateTableFromResult($result) {
    $x    = 1;
    $html = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // Add the open-table tag
        $html = '<table>';

        // Iterate through the columns and add them to our variable
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            $html .= "<tr><th>".$column."</th><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
        }

        // Add the close-table tag
        $html .= "</table>";

        // Now, since we've added all the rows for that person, 
        // create, populate and store the file
        file_put_contents("newfile".$x.".php", $html);

        // Increment $x before we jump to the next person
        $x++;
    }

    // However, this will only return the table for the last person
    return $html;
}
```

I also changed your `fopen` and `copy` (which didn't really make sense) to one simple command: [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

A big shout out to @ishegg that helped narrow down the issue

Answer (score 2):

By default, the fetch mode for [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) is [`MYSQLI_BOTH`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-parameters), which means it's getting each result in associative *and* numeric form. That, in addition to your double-looping over the results, gives you the results you're getting.

To fix it, you can use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` (or use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)), so it only gets each row once.

```
function generateTableFromResult($result) {
    $x = 1;
    $html = "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            copy("persons.php","newfile".$x.".php");
            $html.="<tr><th>".$column."</th><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
            $myfile = fopen("newfile".$x.".php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($myfile, $html);
        }
    $x++;
    }
    $html.="</table>";
    return $html;
}
```

Or, keeping your original function:

```
function generateTableFromResult($result) {
    $x = 1;
    $html = "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            copy("persons.php","newfile".$x.".php");
            $html.="<tr><th>".$column."</th><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
            $myfile = fopen("newfile".$x.".php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($myfile, $html);
        }
    $x++;
    }
    $html.="</table>";
    return $html;
}
```

Also, as @MagnusEriksson points out, you're appending the content to `$html` each time, so you will still get both results in the second file. To avoid this, put `$html = "table";` inside the `foreach` loop:

```
function generateTableFromResult($result) {
    $x = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            copy("persons.php","newfile".$x.".php");
            $html = "<table>";
            $html.="<tr><th>".$column."</th><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
            $html.="</table>";
            $myfile = fopen("newfile".$x.".php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($myfile, $html);
        }
        $x++;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: The first file is fine, while the second newly created file contains both tables.

Comment: Try debugging first without the file handling. If you `echo $value;` inside the `foreach()` and comment out everything else, what's the result? There are some problems with your logic there.

Comment: @kapelnick - Well, you're actually _appending_ content to the `$html` variable (by using `.=`) so yes, it will contain all previous data as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Good eye, I missed that. Edited the answer.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson removing the dot resulted in a disaster. Which logical mistakes are you reffering to?

Comment: @kapelnick - You can't just remove the dot. What is the end goal? What should the files actually contain? Do you mean to have one complete `<table>....</table>` per person/file? Then you need to reset (`$html = '<table>';`) the `$html` between the `while` and the `foreach`. Then you need to append to that variable like you're currently doing in the foreach. Then _after_ the `foreach` you need to copy and write to the file.

Comment: One complete `<table>...</table>` per person/file. Exactly that. The corrected answer now only writes the name of the last `column`. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @kapelnick yeah you completely lost me now. I don't really know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @kapelnick - So what do you expect that function to return (since you return $html)? You need to be explicit about how you want the content and what you expect your code to produce. It's very hard to guess from your original question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Edit the question, I hope this is what you asked.